# VB - Copy all rows with cell like ''

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will search through my range and copy the entire row where cell like '*01'. It copies and paste to the sheet i need but it loops and copies just the same row, maybe i dont need the loop if there is an easier way to accomplish this. again all I really need is to copy all the rows that have a cell like'*01'and paste it in my new worksheet. This goes to every 5 rows down looking for the cell with that value.  Thank you so much!

```
     Sub Macro3()
  'ctrl + l
  Dim GetBook As String

Dim cell As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range

GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name


Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("d7:d500")

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
For Each cell In SrchRng
'And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0))
      If cell Like "*01" Then cell.Offset(0, 0).EntireRow.Copy
    Next cell

 Loop

    Windows("TestCov.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal

 Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        Windows(GetBook).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
```

Comment: vb.net <> vba or whatever that is

Comment: What exactly is this address?  `Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select`  You're starting with a fixed location, going to the a sub-range within it (which is only one cell, so it's going to return the same thing you started with), then offsetting from there.  Why not `Range("iv2")` and be done with it?

Comment: Why is the paste outside the loop?

Comment: I needed that iv1 part because it paste in a new sheet into the first empty column (fist empty cell at row one) and since i dont know how many copied rows their will be i need it to find the next available

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely re-write.  You will have to write different code to set destination start and the search range.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim destination As Range
    Set destination = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
    Set SrchRng = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A500")

    For Each source In SrchRng
        If source.Text Like "*01" Then
            source.EntireRow.Copy
            destination.PasteSpecial _
                Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next source
End Sub
```

Comment: This is now working, copying each row that contains "*01" to the new worksheet, BUT when I open a new workbook and run the macro it will copy the rows i need but replace the ones I already have. So I need a way for it to begin on the next available cell in row 1, range("iv1")xltleft should have worked. see next comment

Comment: Sub Macro3()
'ctrl + l
Dim GetBook As String
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim destination As Range
GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set destination = Workbooks("TestCov.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("d7:d500")
For Each Source In SrchRng
If Source.Text Like "*01" Then
Source.EntireRow.Copy
destination.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Set destination = destination.Offset(0, 1)
End If
    Next Source
End Sub

Comment: You could replace the `Set destination` line with whatever works better.